# How to replicate my for loop using "map" with Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to implement this logic in Spark and Scala. The initial logic is specified in Java (I hope that it's not a big issue:) ).

```
Map<Object,List<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<Object,List<Integer>>();

for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
   String module = nodes.getAttribute(i);
   Integer k_i = nodes.getK(i);
   if (!myMap.containsKey(module)) {
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      list.add(k_i);
      myMap.put(module,list);
   }
   else {
      List<Integer> list = myMap.get(module);
      list.add(k_i);
      myMap.put(module,list);
   }
}
```

I have `nodesRDD` that is `RDD[Node]`, but I do not know how to incrementally create `myMap` while checking its content in each iteration.
Any hint will be highly valuable.

```
val myMap = nodes.map( node => {
  val module = node.getAttribute()
  (module, node)
})
.groupBy(_._1)
```

This gives me `RDD[(Long, Iterable[(Long,Array(Node))])]`. But I need `RDD[(Long, Array(Node))]`.

Comment: Where is `myMap` defined? It isn't in the closure of the `map()`, so therefore it's not immediately available to any Spark Executor

Comment: `map` is not a replacement for a for-loop. It is for you to **modify** `nodes` content into a new RDD

Comment: @cricket_007: But shouldn't I modify `nodes` by looping through it using `map`? `foreach` will not return any value

Comment: So, nobody among downvoters is clever enough to make any hint?

Comment: I think that the problem is that the first code snippet is in Java, whereas the second in Scala. You should clarify in which language you need help.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin: Thanks. I though that it's enough to provide a tag `scala` and my sample solution in Scala, as well as to say "I am trying to implement this logic in Spark and Scala" in the first line of the question.

Comment: `foreach` doesn't need to return anything. You are adding to an external `HashMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This gives me RDD[(Long, Iterable[(Long,Array(Node))])]

It is impossible. If

> `nodesRDD` that is `RDD[Node]`,

and `getAttribute` is of type `T` then:

```
nodes.map( node => {
  val module = node.getAttribute()
  (module, node)
})
```

should be `RDD[(T, Node)]` and `.groupBy(_._1)` should give `RDD[(T, Iterable[(T, Node)])]`

> But I need RDD[(Long, Array(Node))].

Then

```
myMap.mapValues(_.map(_._2).toArray)
```

Of course:

```
nodes.groupBy(_.getAttribute()).mapValues(_.toArray)
```

or

```
nodes.map( node => {
  (node.getAttribute(), node)
}).groupByKey
```

are much simpler